# Meaning of "That'll get steam on the table."

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I was watching a movie featuring a conversation between two men. This is an attempt at transcribing the conversation:

> Man #1: "I'm redistributing wealth. It's quite spiritual.  Karma,
>   boy."

I'm not certain which of two things the second man responds with.  Here are my two guesses:

> Man #2: "I'll get steam on the table."

or

> Man #2: "That'll get steam on the table."

For context, the first man is an armed robber.  I'm wondering which of those two sentences was most likely the second man's response, and what it means.

Comment: It might be worth saying which movie, and whether it's in English or not. There are often transcripts available for those that can find them and things can often be misheard. Welcome to ELU.

Comment: The movie is "My Name Is Lenny". And it's in english. The problem is my mother language is not english. In english subtitle its "That'll get steam on the table.". But I hear " I'll get steam on the table." Probably, the second man responds with the second sentence.So what can be meaning of this sentence. The second man responded with that after the first man said "Karma, boy."

Comment: It's worth pointing out that said movie takes place, supposably, in Britain during the 1960s and 70s.  It is also supposable that the dialect would be of a working class, East London variety.  This could possibly be an idiom not necessarily known to most English speakers.

Comment: Steam is hot and is used as propulsion in engines, specially since the industrial revolution. Table is where you lay a game, be it either cards or a board game. It is a symbol for life, or the story; the game. The whole phrase means getting things to work, like steam makes machines move. Potentially temperature is also implied. Hot things are active, hard to handle.

Comment: The same phrase appears in a quote of Lawrence of Arabia's actor Petr O'Toole: "I put steam on the table by being an actor. That is how I live. The longer I live, the more expensive it becomes. So I do my work. And I can't be immensely picky. How many beautiful scripts come in one's lifetime? I have had more than anybody, practically."

Comment: @mama that’s pretty much an answer. Maybe check some online dictionaries and add a reference for the Peter O’Toole quote and it should be grand!

Comment: I'm going to make a wild guess that "steam on the table" is a poorer class reference to a Hot Meal steaming on the table, the poorer classes being where such a thing would be a worthy goal for hard work.

Comment: @Pam Well, all of that is my interpretation. If the phrase is an idiom, then it could potentially mean something entirely unrelated to any symbolic meaning of the words involved and all I said would be wrong. The interview with Peter O'Toole is [here](https://www.usatoday.com/story/life/people/2013/12/15/peter-o-toole-interview/4032597/).

Answer (score 1):

From the Oxford English Dictionary we get:

> 10. [ < steam v.] A dish cooked by steaming. colloq.
>
> 1900   Soc. Life Brit. Army 98   Apart from soup, the cooking arrangements will only allow of Tommy being given his choice between a bake and a steam. A steam resembles what we have been taught to call Irish stew.

So the phrase "get steam on the table" is likely an upgrade of "put bread on the table": an idiom for earning money. A hot stew with meat would be considered better than simple bread for a working class family.

It’s also worth considering the phrase "[steam table](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/steam+table)" which describes a specific table for keeping things warm. Although the phrase "get steam on the table" is not uncommon.

In context, the robber is getting money through robbery or "wealth redistribution". The other man probably comments **"That'll get steam on the table"** in reference to the fact that armed robbery will result in money for the robber.